# Panic: Index out of bounds | Solidity | truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I am trying to deploy the following smart contract in ganache-cli using truffle framework.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract Sample {
    address[] public owners;
    constructor(address[] memory temp) {
        for(uint256 i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
            owners[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
   Deploying 'Sample'
   ------------------
✖ Transaction submission failed with error -32000: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"Sample" hit a require or revert statement with the following reason given:
   * Panic: Index out of bounds


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Sample" hit a require or revert statement with the following reason given:
   * Panic: Index out of bounds
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
address[] public owners;
```

This line declares the array with 0 items.

```
owners[i] = temp[i];
```

And this line is trying to assign into `i`th item that does not exist in the array.

**Solution**: You need to use the `push()` function to resize the array and set the new item value.

```
for(uint256 i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
    owners.push(temp[i]);
}
```